# Retrieving the float value from xml using Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to retrieve the data from the XML using the Sql Server.

**Fetching the Data From SQL Server**

```
DECLARE @salary float=null
      DECLARE @xml xml

      SET @xml = '<root><Salary>0.0</Salary></root>'

      select 
      @salary = case when ISNULL(x.v.value('Salary[1]','nvarchar(100)'),'0') != '0' then  x.v.value('Salary[1]','float') else 10000 end
      from @xml.nodes('/root') x(v);        

      print @salary
```

When the Salary is 0.0, the case condition is working correctly as it is displaying the output as 0.

But when we are using the Salary as 0 (without decimal), the case statement working in correctly and displaying 99 as output.

**Fetching the Data From SQL Server**

```
DECLARE @salary float=null
  DECLARE @xml xml

  SET @xml = '<root><Salary>0</Salary></root>'

  select 
  @salary = case when ISNULL(x.v.value('Salary[1]','nvarchar(100)'),'0') != '0' then  x.v.value('Salary[1]','float') else 10000 end
  from @xml.nodes('/root') x(v);

  print @salary
```

Comment: You should NEVER use the FLOAT data type for money as it is an "approximate" number. Better to use either MONEY, SMALLMONEY, DECIMAL or NUMERIC... That said, Your values are displaying correctly based on the FLOAT data type. Float will not display a decimal point if there is nothing behind it. Check the results of this... SELECT CAST(0 AS FLOAT), CAST(0.0 AS FLOAT), CAST(1.1 AS FLOAT);

Comment: Thanks for the info. Its just a demo to illustrate the issue.

Comment: You code seems to be working fine. What you're describing is standard behavior both the FLOAT and REAL data types. Change data type and you'll the issue go away. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following Query will be helpful.

```
DECLARE @DocHandle INT,
        @Xml NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @XMl = N'<root><Salary>0.00</Salary></root>'
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @Xml

SELECT CASE WHEN Salary <> 0 THEN Salary ELSE 10000 END AS Salary
FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle , '/root')
WITH (Salary DECIMAL(18,3), 'Salary')
```

OUTPUT:

```
Salary
--------
10000
```